# Is it possible to divide functions of an python class into different files ?

Tags: python, class, python-module

Suppose I write a very large class and to cope with that length I need to divide the source into multiple file. How could I spread that source code in such a way? If it not viable, how do the large libraries handle coding large scale programs ?

Comment: They do so by using the Single Responsibility Principle. A class should not be that large.

Comment: Agreed. If you need to make `class Bike`, feel free to make separate files for `class Wheel`, `class Tire`, `class Spoke` and import them into `Bike,` but do not make `Bike` a million-line gargantuan program.

Comment: Just to provide context (and some crawler bait): This is called partial class in C#. It is used (AFAIK mainly) to separate auto-generated and handwritten parts of the same class. Splitting into two classes is not desirable because of visibility.

Comment: If you did not ask for best practices on large library maintenance, this question would be exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/9638446/2157640

Comment: And this is an answer, IMO: http://stackoverflow.com/a/295760/2157640